# Problem verifying contract code on rinkeby

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, rinkeby

I've deployed a basic `MichaelCoin` ERC20 contract without issue and able to interact with it via geth console. My issue is verifying it on http://rinkeby.etherscan.io.

I am inputting `MichaelCoin` as the contract name and when I run `truffle version` I get:

```
Truffle v3.4.5 (core: 3.4.5)
Solidity v0.4.11 (solc-js)
```

The compiler version I am choosing is `v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810`

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Note: Contract was created during Txn# [0xb9c93fc42899022b578594706fcb770899e976054c1377df22f02273c6608a37]
 Result: Does not match the input creation bytecode found at this address

Sorry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for 'MichaelCoin' does NOT match the Contract Creation Code for [0xba598b093bf468053ad740729466045b17701d87].

Contract name(s) found: 'MichaelCoin' 
Unable to Verify Contract at this point time.
```

Contract address on rinkeby etherscan is https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xba598b093bf468053ad740729466045b17701d87

Here is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract MichaelCoin {


  mapping (address => uint256) balances;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  string public name = "Michael Coin";
  string public symbol = "MC";
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
  uint256 public totalAmount = 1000000;

  event Transfer (address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
  event Approval (address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

  function MichaelCoin() {
    // constructor
    balances[msg.sender] = totalAmount;
  }
  function totalSupply() constant returns(uint) {
    return totalAmount;
    }
  function transfer (address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value
        && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
      balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
      balances[_to] += _value;
      Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
      return true;
    } else { return false; }
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
    if(balances[_from] >= _value
        && _value > 0
        && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]
        && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value) {

        balances[_from] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  function() {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: I think you are using different account.you have created MichaelCoin with "0xa395650f5e23cb33fad82a0d1924747183b126a0"  address and your trying to invoke the published contract with your new address "0xba598b093bf468053ad740729466045b17701d87" . can you please go to geth and  try "geth account list" If you could see  0xa395650f5e23cb33fad82a0d1924747183b126a0 the do the following geth --account "0xa395650f5e23cb33fad82a0d1924747183b126a0" and run truffle. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking me to do. 0xa395650f5e23cb33fad82a0d1924747183b126a0 is the account I created the contract with using truffle as the default account. This issue is on etherscan though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Found this thread - https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/456

Need to go to https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract2 and set the Runs (Optimizer) to `0`